# Bickepacking saddle bag touches rear wheel on mountain bike

Tags: mountain-bike, downhill, 29er, bikepacking

I am planning a 2 weeks trip following a mountain bike itinerary consisting of 650 km including single trails and 25'000 m of positive (and negative) elevation.
I planned to go with my full suspension mountain enduro bike and I got the Ortlieb [seatpack 16.5L](https://www.ortlieb.com/seat-pack+F9901) and [handlebar-pack 15L](https://www.ortlieb.com/handlebar-pack+F9921) to pack all the camping gear. During the test ride last weekend, I was pretty pleased to be able to pack everything I needed in those bags.

The issue is that while riding on single trail going downhill, I was forced to keep the rear suspension to its tightest setting and even then, the seatpack was touching the wheel every now and then. Here is a picture of the setup:
[image: bike setup with bikepacking bags]
The bike is a [Canyon Strive](https://www.canyon.com/fr-ch/mountain-bikes/enduro-bikes/strive/strive-cf-5.0/2004.html?dwvar_2004_pv_rahmenfarbe=RD&quantity=1) with 29in wheels.

So the question is: **how to avoid having the seatpack touching the rear wheel when going downhill ?**
Putting the saddle higher is certainly not an optimal solution has it's already too high to be really comfortable going downhill. I was thinking about maybe switching the rear wheel with a 27.5in but I don't know how easy it would be and if it would be comfortable to ride for 2 weeks.

Comment: Which parts of the saddle bag actually interfere with the tire? Could it be the issue only occurs because the unsupported tail of the bag flexes downwards in the very conditions that cause the suspension to compress?

Comment: A bamboo stick packed into the saddlebag could make it stiffer.

Comment: The Specialized BigHit used a similar set using a 24" rear tire to increase  rear suspension travel. Some reviewers did mention the rear not rolling over obstacles as well as the front.

Comment: I realize it may be hard to answer this, but: is the contact caused entirely by the wheel bouncing up to the bag, or is the bag also bouncing down to hit the wheel? If the latter, you may be able to stiffen the bag enough to prevent hits; if the former, you'll need to reduce travel no matter what. There are some bikepacking seatbags that include struts. Maybe also you could use a fender.

Comment: @AdamRice The contact is caused by the wheel bouncing up, it actually touches the bag quite close to the mounting point (the picture has been taken before tightening more the bag so it bends more upward).